# Cant make my site available to the internet

Tags: apache, apache2

Hi I'm using ubuntu as server OS for my webhosting but I'm having problem redirecting my domainname to my server Here are my /etc/hosts file and /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite file.

hosts file:

127.0.0.1   www.lowkey.se

## The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

sites-available/file:

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.lowkey.se

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/doost/
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/doost/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

And a screenshot from my domain name provider:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I am no expert on Ubuntu but i have enough experience on Apache. Please update what is the error message you are getting. Also please check if the Apache is working/ started properly. Try access http://localhost/ If that works means that your Apache is working fine.

Comment: Iäm not getting any error message. I try to access www.lowkey.se but the call dont get any respond from my server.

Comment: Possibly your Apache has not started. Please check if there are some logs in "APACHE_ROOT_FOLDER\logs" folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please comment following three lines in your Apache configuration and then restart Apache :

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/doost/
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

For commenting replace them as follows :

```
#DocumentRoot /var/www/doost/
#ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
#CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: may I ask why I should comment out the documentRoot?

Comment: okay I did as you said and disabled/enabled the doost file and restarted apache

Comment: I tried your Apache configurations in my Apache server and the error came as : Syntax error on line 597 of C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf:
DocumentRoot must be a directory

Comment: localhost is working fine. I get the site up when I target the doost folder such as 127.0.0.1/doost/ I have www.lowkey.se registered on a domain name provider and I've redirected the domain to the servers ip. and according to the guides I've been following it should work now. but I cant get the same site up on www.lowkey.se as I get at 127.0.0.1

Comment: Then its clear that host file changes are now picked up. Use : 127.0.0.1 localhost www.lowkey.se and then restart the Computer once.

Comment: I just came to think maybe my ISP provider blocks port 80?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19918/discussion-between-amber-and-user1683645)